# How can I uninstall Tensorflow 2.0.0-alpha0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using sublime text editor to run tensorflow commands using pythin 3.7. In particular I am trying to run: `tf.enable_eager_execution()` but I get the error:
`AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'enable_eager_execution'` 
I have checked my version of tensorflow using: `print(tf.__version__)` and the version is: *2.0.0-alpha0*.

What's odd is that I have uninstalled tensorflow completely using `pip3 uninstall tensorflow` and I still have that version running.

From reading around I believe I cant run `tf.enable_eager_execution()` because of my tensorflow version and thats why I am trying to uninstall it. Ive also tried to explicitly call it using `tensorflow.contrib.eager` but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TensorFlow 2.0* has [eager execution by default](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/guide/effective_tf2#eager_execution). To disable eager execution use

`tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()`

Comment: So I don't need to use `tf.enable_eager_execution()` at all?